# Share Dialogues - Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, facebook, share

*Update - Edit*

I'm very new to the idea of share dialogues and I'd like to incorporate this idea into my site.

I have a reaction timer game that displays the user's reaction time in seconds in a modal popup. I'd love to share the reaction time that the user got to Facebook. It would have some text like:

[name] was playing the Reaction Time game and scored [var=reaction_time].

The share button will be on the Modal footer for the user to click.

I have the share button activating this function:

```
       function share_result() {
    let bestTime = document.getElementById("time").value;
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://mysite.site/',
  quote: 'I scored ' + bestTime
}, function(response){});
}
```

I can get the pop-up called and the "I scored " but the variable is undefined.

Maybe I am calling it wrong?

Any clues as to what is missing?

Comment: You need to use your own button, and assign it a click handler, that then calls `FB.ui` with those parameters.

Comment: _“And is this even correct?”_ - this will only _suggest_ a quote to the user, that they will be able to _change_ (or remove) before they post. So even if you suggest the quote `I just scored 50 s, at the Reaction Time game...`, no one is stopping the user from making that into 5 seconds instead …

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand this a bit better now. I'll try it in a few hours and see if I can get it working.

Comment: I just can't get it to work at all - I can get the pop-up window, but I can't get any variable or text into that window plus it spits an error about the website. 

I am not quite sure where to go to next on this.

Comment: function share_result() {
    let bestTime = document.getElementById("time").value;
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://somewebsite.site/',
  quote: 'I scored ' + bestTime
}, function(response){});
}

Apparently that just gives "undefined" so I am guessing I don't know how to parse in a variable into the Facebook quote?

Answer (score 0):

*solved

```
function share_result() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://mysite.site',
    quote: 'I scored ' + window.time.toFixed(3) + ' s in the Reaction Time game at my site!'
  }, function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error_message) {
      alert('Posting completed.');
    } else {
      alert('Error while posting.');
    }
  });
}
```

The problem I encountered was not sharing a global value.